# Django Rest 'api-docs' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm setting the docs for my api and when I ask for (http://localhost:8000/api/v0/docs/) The app show me this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /api/v0/docs/
'api-docs' is not a registered namespace
```

when try to do this

```
<script src="{% url **'api-docs:schema-js'** %}"></script>
```

this is my urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import views

from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'goals', views.GoalViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^goals/$', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title')),
]
```

I added the namespace to include_docs_urls but it doesn't work. (I have installed coreapi, pygments and markdown).

Beforehand thanks for helping me.

Comment: Try moving the docs url in your **main** `urls.py` file.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/d0L3jVMqp2Y, https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4984 Seems like DRF 3.6.2 docs break, if you add API version to your url (like `/api/v0` as you do).

Comment: @wencakisa yes, I moved the docs/ url to the urls.py main file and it worked. Thank you!.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Would you mind if I post it as an answer?

Comment: @wencakisa You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should move your `docs` url pattern into your **main** `urls.py` file. This is still a problem in DRF, there is also an issue opened on the official GitHub source: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4984

The official developer of Django REST Framework, [Tom Christie](https://github.com/tomchristie), says:

> It's important enough that I'd like to see it highly prioritized, but there's a lot of other things going on at the moment too. Even after we release 3.6.3, there's still also all the work towards 3.7.0's realtime integration.

So your `docs` pattern should not have *any* prefixes (like `api/v0/`).

In conclusion, change your main `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='API Title'))
```